What is the reason for the ratios of square units not being the same as the ratios of units
When you have a square with side length 1 yard you get an area of 1 yd$^2$. When you convert the units of this square to feet you get a square with side length 3 and therefore an area of 9 square feet. This means that the ratio of these units when dealing with area isn’t the same as when dealing with length and it isn’t constant either. The identity property of multiplication seem to also be weird in this case because the area is the same as the length when it equals 1 yd but when you change the units the are changes from 3 to 9. Please explain this to me and what the idea is called so I can learn more about it.

$ (1 \cdot \text{yd})^2 = (1 \cdot (3 \cdot \text{ft}))^2 = 1^2 \cdot (3^2 \cdot \text{ft}^2) = 9 \cdot \text{ft}^2$

See dimensional analysis.

For a square,$A=l^2$ where $l$ is the side. If we take units $a$ and $b$,
$$A=A_aa^2=A_bb^2 \implies \frac{A_a}{A_b}=\frac{a^2}{b^2}$$
Here $A_a=\frac{A}{a^2}$(same for unit $b$)
So
$$\frac{\frac{A}{a^2}}{\frac{A}{b^2}}=\frac{a^2}{b^2}$$
Square rooting both sides,
$$\frac{\frac{\sqrt A}{a}}{\frac{\sqrt A}{b}}=\frac{a}{b}$$
But $\sqrt A=l$, so
$$\frac{\frac{l}{a}}{\frac{l}{b}}=\frac{a}{b}\implies \frac{l_a}{l_b}=\frac{a}{b}$$
This can be studied further using dimensional analysis

When converting units, the conversion factor for area is the square of the conversion factor for length. Here’s how it works:

Length: $1 \, \text{yard} = 3 \, \text{feet}$.
Area: For a square with a side of 1 yard (which is $1 \, \text{yd}^2$ in area), when converted to feet, each side becomes 3 feet. Thus, the area becomes
$$
  3 \, \text{ft} \times 3 \, \text{ft} = 9 \, \text{ft}^2.
  $$

This occurs because area is a two-dimensional measurement, so the conversion factor is squared. This principle is known as $\textbf{dimensional analysis}.$
